# Is there a $P$-space linearly Lindelöf and non-Lindelöf?

Tags: general-topology

A completely regular topological space $(X,\tau)$ is a $P$-space, if every $G_\delta$-subset of $X$ is open (i.e $\tau$ is closed under countable intersection).

A topological space $X$ is linearly Lindelöf if for every open cover of $X$, linearly ordered by the subset relation, has a countable subcover.

Is there a $P$-space linearly Lindelöf and non-Lindelöf?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/140224/is-there-a-p-space-linearly-lindelof-and-non-lindelof Please, do not double post your question on MSE and on MO. If you see that your question is still without an answer on one of these sites after a few days, you can still post it on the other site.